# Getting rid of some sensitive data in a git repo

Tags: git

If you realize that you saved some sensitive data (user:pass, an access token etc) in some version of the git repositiory, what can you do to get rid of it, without sacrificing the whole repository?. Is it possible to scrap that current revision only. Will git figure out the gaps automatically?

Answer (score 3):

GitHub has a nice article about it:

https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data

Essentially, you use `git filter-branch` to rewrite the history of your project, removing files with sensitive content.

Comment: But make sure you have a backup of your repo when playing around with `filter-branch` and forcing the gc to remove old blobs. ;)