# How can I completely delete a file that was uploaded to Gitlab in an issue comment?

Tags: gitlab

Someone uploaded (attached) a file in a Gitlab issue comment. They did not mean to share that file publicly. I can delete the comment, but the file is still available via the original direct url. The file is at:

```
https://gitlab.com/<username>/<repo>/uploads/<hash>/<filename>
```

Is there any way to completely remove files from this uploads directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting rid of some sensitive data in a git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899713/getting-rid-of-some-sensitive-data-in-a-git-repo)

Comment: This file is not committed to the git repo. But I guess it is possible it could be stored in another git repo or in a branch of the git repo, but this isn't something that is exposed to the users of gitlab. Gitlab stores uploaded files somehow on their backend (I don't know how).

Comment: According to the currently unsolved issue [Attachment Manager](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/16229) that is only possible directly in the filesystem of the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I raised a case with GitLab support and they were able to provide a solution for this. Using GraphQL, you can delete any uploaded files you have access to.

Navigate to GitLab's GraphQL explorer: https://gitlab.com/-/graphql-explorer
Use this query to delete your file:

```
mutation{
  uploadDelete(input: { projectPath: "YOUR_PROJECT_PATH", secret: "YOUR_SECRET_HASH_KEY" , filename: "FILE_NAME" }) { 
    upload {
      id
      size
      path 
    }
    errors
  }
}
```

Example:
If your uploaded file path is `https://gitlab.com/s_shaik/ci256986/uploads/abefe4f256e91ffc212c40605ae91ab3/ci.yml`
Then
`projectPath`: "s_shaik/ci256986"
`secret`: "abefe4f256e91ffc212c40605ae91ab3"
`filename`: "ci.yml"

On success you will receive a response like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "uploadDelete": {
      "upload": {
        "id": "gid://gitlab/Upload/<id>",
        "size": <file_size>,
        "path": "@hashed/some/path/to/file"
      },
      "errors": []
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

*Short version:* There's server-side [Uploads administration | GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee////////administration/uploads.html), but little to nothing else.
*Update:* Please refer to [GitJiggyWithIt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77489608) if you're comfortable using the API and GraphQL - it's a working solution if you still hold the URL to the file you want deleted. (If you removed the reference, the editing history may help).

#### TLDR:

For the owner of a repository, there seems to be no way to get hold of these uploads directly, there even doesn't seem to be a way to list all uploads pertaning to a specific repository (or user/owner), let alone modify them.

### use-cases where this would be desirable:

- deletion of data that should *not* be exposed but has been erroneously.
- down-scaling of oversized files (images, pdfs, etc)
- replacing files with updated versions
- deleting space-hogs that are no longer needed.
- deleting files that got uploaded accidentally by trigger-happy mice or when the result of a previous upload didn't show in time for the impatient user.

Making these files changeable would cause several issues rooted in their current/previous immutable status:
Users aware of this status will frequently re-use the url to an already uploaded file for perusal in other issues, or the associated wiki (even across projects) to avoid duplication. Afaik, there is no such thing as a link-count for upload items, so deleting an item might result in orphaned references, and changing an uploaded file might render other references out-of-context.

It would solve the serious issue of leaked information, though. The only way I have found so far to remove a file would be to send a prayer to the administrator of the gitlab server, and ask him/her to take care of the uploads directory on the server, as described in [Uploads administration | GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee////////administration/uploads.html)

Comment: Thanks! This seems like the appropriate answer. I haven't had success with Gitlab support on this, as it is a free account. I can keep trying, I suppose.

Comment: Maybe you could reference the problem in an issue - that way the impact might be visible to those reading issues (and possibly adding improvements if the issue is motivating or important enought (I found more than once that motivating gets further than anything else). Referenced in an issue, it might also catch the curious eye of someone with administrative blessings on the server in question - just make sure that the issue doesn't leak the link in question...